# Using markdown formatting on queried SQL in flask app

Tags: sqlite, flask, markdown

In a flask app, I am retrieving some entries from an sqlite database, for display on my html page, code below:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('index.html', entries=entries)
```

I would like to use markdown to format the content. I already have markdown installed, and would like to use it on my sql query just like it is used below on raw data.

```
import markdown
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Markup

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def index():
  content = """
Chapter
=======

Section
-------

* Item 1
* Item 2
"""
  content = Markup(markdown.markdown(content))
  return render_template('index.html', **locals())

app.run(debug=True)
```

Which works to yield the chapter/section/item stuff as marked down when it is pulled up in an html template. **I do not want to install Flask-Markdown** I just want to do this with regular markdown, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options:

1. You can render the markdown before passing it to `render_template`:

   ```
   @app.route('/')
   def index():
       db = get_db()
       cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
       entries = [Markup(markdown(entry) for entry in cur.fetchall()]
       return render_template('index.html', entries=entries)
   ```
2. You can register a template filter and then use it in your template:

   ```
   @app.template_filter("markdown")
   def render_markdown(markdown_text):
       return Markup(markdown(markdown_text))
   ```

   Then, in your template you can just call the `markdown` filter:

   ```
   {% for entry in entries %}
   <article>
       {{entry | markdown}}
   </article>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

Comment: Thanks a million. 

Simply registering a template filter, and then calling that filter in the template like so {{ entry.text |markdown }} does the trick.

I don't even have to do the entries = [Markup(markdown....] stuff

It works fine with entries =cur.fetchall()